# Flutter how can i add custom image marker on google map

Tags: flutter

I am suing Flutter plugin to show map in my app which is done issue is I have fixed long and latitude value and I need to show a custom image marker on that values. Its showing a simple red marker now but don't know how to show the image icon.

```
class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _onMapCreated();
  }

  final currentPostion = LatLng(24.916404, 67.130654);

  final Map<String, Marker> _markers = {};
  _onMapCreated()  {
    setState(() {
      _markers.clear();
        final marker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('asda'),
          position: LatLng(24.916404, 67.130654),

          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: 'dsaa',
            snippet: 'sss',
          ),
        );
        _markers['saa'] = marker;
      }
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: GestureDetector(
              onTap:(){
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
          centerTitle: true,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('images/nav.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          title: Text('My Location', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'UbuntuBold'),),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.notifications_none,
                size: 33,
              ),
            )
          ]),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: currentPostion,
          zoom: 20,
        ),
        markers: _markers.values.toSet(),

      ),

    );
  }
```

you can see i have added marker in code butnot able to change it to image.

Answer (score 0):

`GoogleMap` widget contains property `markers` which is a `Set<Marker>`.
https://medium.com/@zeh.henrique92/google-maps-flutter-marker-circle-and-polygon-c71f4ea64498